# conditional where

Tags: c#, linq

I need to write a conditional query in linq:

**if field.val1 == 0:**

```
var q = from field in cw.fields
select field
```

**if field.val1 != 0 and field.val2 == 0:**

```
var q = from field in cw.fields
where field.val1 == 1
select field
```

**if field.val1 != 0 and field.val2 != 0:**

```
var q = from field in cw.fields
where field.val1 == 1 and field.val2 == 1
select field
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @Eric J title is the same, but my query comes smaller and bigger deponds on conditions

Comment: @mohammad adibi: your query is similar - it implies knowing how `&&` and `||` work, so it's trivial.

Comment: @sinelaw ijust write 3 query and control by if else, but i think it's wrong

Comment: @zerkm would you explain more

Comment: @mohammad adibi: `(cond1) || (cond2) || (cond3)` ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your condition depends on the values your querying, you have to just extend your `where` clause with additional cases using `||`:

```
var q = from field in cw.fields
where
    (field.val1 == 0) || 
    (field.val1 != 0 and field.val2 == 0 && field.val1 == 1) ||
    (field.val1 != 0 and field.val2 != 0 && field.val1 == 1 and field.val2 == 1)
select field
```

Comment: `field.val1 != 0 && field.val1 == 1` --- the former is a bit redundant isn't it?

Comment: @zerkms Yes, it is. But I didn't want to remove that to make answer more clear for OP. The last case could be just `field.val1 == 1 and field.val2 == 1`. I'm pretty sure database engine will perform the optimization anyway.

Comment: OP doesn't care of clarity - they just will copy-paste it without even trying to get how it works :-) (+1, it makes sense indeed)

Comment: thank you i must check it, but i can't understand it, is there any source or tutorial?

Comment: You don't understand how `&&` and `||` work in c#? The tutorial you're looking for is called *c# for beginners* or *programming in c#*.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek i got it, i didn't know && || work in query! thanks

Comment: let me check and put answered

Answer (score 2):

@MarcinJuraszek's answer will work but let me give a different perspective.

First of all, ditch the sql style syntax. It gets in the way, obscures what is actually going on and is generally just a feel-good abstraction rather than one that will result in more communicative code. Let's rewrite things using lambda syntax

```
IEnumerable<string> getFields(SomeField field, YourDatabase cw) {
  if(field.val1 == 0:)
    return cw.fields.ToList();
  if(field.val1 != 0 and field.val2 == 0)
     return cw.fields.Where(f => f.val1 ==1).ToList();
  if(field.val1 != 0 and field.val2 != 0)
     return cw.fields.Where(f => f.val1 == 1 and f.val2 == 1).ToList();
}
```

note that the only way things differ is the lambda, and a lambda is an object, in this case, an Expression object! So you can use a very standard abstract factory pattern here

```
return cw.fields.Where(matchingCondition(field)).ToList();

//elsewhere...
Expression<Func<SomeField, bool>> matchingCondition(SomeField field) {
  if(field.val1 == 0:)                     return f => true;
  if(field.val1 != 0 and field.val2 == 0)  return f => f.val1 == 1
  if(field.val1 != 0 and field.val2 != 0)  return f => f.val1 == 1 and f.val2 == 1;
  throw new InvalidOperationException("No match to condition");
}
```